# entity framework Code First One-to-Many relationships in Web.API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, one-to-many, relationship

I'm trying to create a one to many relationship using entity framework to convert the json object using Web.API return.

I am creating a scenario that a User has many features emails.

However json file in the User entity that brings contains a list of Emails that appear always empty.

**User Entity**

```
[DataContract]
public class UsuarioEntity : BaseEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Ativado { get; set; } 

    [DataMember] 
    public ICollection<EmailEntity> Emails { get; private set; }
}
```

**Email Entity**

```
 [DataContract]
public class EmailEntity : BaseEntity
{

    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool Principal { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public UsuarioEntity Usuario { get; set; }

}
```

**Fluent API**

**UsuarioConfiguration**

```
            ToTable("tbl_usuarios");

        HasKey(a => new {a.Id, a.UserName});

        Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("cd_id_usuario");

        Property(a => a.UserName)
            .HasMaxLength(32)
            .HasColumnName("nm_usuario");

        Property(a => a.Password)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(32)
            .HasColumnName("tx_senha");

        Property(a => a.DataCadastro) 
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("dt_cadastro");

        HasMany(o => o.Emails)
            .WithRequired();
```

**EmailConfiguration**

```
            ToTable("tbl_email_usuario");

        HasKey(a => new { a.Id, a.Email });

        Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .HasColumnName("cd_id_email");

        Property(a => a.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("nm_email");

        Property(a => a.DataCadastro)
            .HasColumnType("datetime")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("dt_cadastro")
```

I tried to use EF with Web api this way:

```
public IQueryable<UsuarioEntity> Get()
{
    PlainContext context = new PlainContext();
    return context.Usuarios;
}
```

Except that the return was not expected

```
[{"Id":1,"Ativado":true,"DataCadastro":"\/Date(1357307720730-0200)\/","Emails":[],"Password":"senha456","UserName":"recapix"}]
```

I own and Registered Emails only they do not appear on Json.

Comment: Are they getting fetched from the database and not appearing in the response XML / JSON or not getting fetched form the database at all

Comment: I'm trying to get the database and serialize to a json file, put the email list is always coming empty, I put items in the database ..

Comment: did you put them directly or via ef ?

Comment: yes I put the data from the Seed of Migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entities don't support lazy loading so you must define explicitly that you want to load related emails as well:

```
return context.Usarios.Include(u => u.Emails);
```

Comment: Worked but I used string name of column in Include ...Lambda don´t work ...Thanks Man ..

Comment: You can use lambdas if you include System.Data.Entity in your namespace declarations

Comment: When I use include, I am getting Bad gateway response when calling api, can you think of something that may cause this problem please?